# Как отловить "Первый выбранный" - в серии событий change checkbox.checked

Tags: javascript

Всем привет подскажите пожалуйста как отловить первый выбранный checkbox

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper'),
     info  = document.querySelector('.info'),
     inp   = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper input');

wrapper.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let check = [];
    const eTarget = e.target;
    
    for(let i = 0; i < inp.length; i++){
     if(inp[i].checked && check.length === 0){
       check[0] = inp[i].value;
       
        
      }

    }
info.innerHTML = `first checked: ${check}`;

});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="group">
        <h4>Item Group 1</h4>
        <div>
            <label for="item-1">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-1" value="1">item1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="item-2">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-2" value="2">item2
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h4>Item Group 2</h4>
        <div>
            <label for="item-3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-3" value="3">item3
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="item-4">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-4" value="4">item4
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">first checked: </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что значит _"отловить"_, чекбоксы у тебя разбегаются, а затем бродят и кусают прохожих? _"Первый выбранный"_ - в порядке следования в разметке, или в серии событий `change`?

Comment: Извините :D 
"Первый выбранный" -  в серии событий change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper'),
     info  = document.querySelector('.info'),
     inp   = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper input');

let check = [];
wrapper.addEventListener('change', e => {
    const eTarget = e.target;
    if (!check.length && eTarget.matches('input[type="checkbox"')) {
      check.push(eTarget);
      info.innerHTML = `first checked: ${eTarget.id}`;
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="group">
        <h4>Item Group 1</h4>
        <div>
            <label for="item-1">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-1" value="1">item1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="item-2">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-2" value="2">item2
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h4>Item Group 2</h4>
        <div>
            <label for="item-3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-3" value="3">item3
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="item-4">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-4" value="4">item4
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">first checked: </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Обработчик продолжит реагировать на события даже после выполнения его основной задачи, впустую расходуя ресурсы (мало, но все же); Проверка свойства объекта "дешевле" проверки соответствия селектору; Плюс, тут никакой потребности в создании массива (переменная под ссылку на DOM-объект прекрасно проверяется с автотипкастом к `boolean` - ее даже инициализировать не обязательно).

Answer (score 2):

Для получения первого элемента чекбокса, который был выбран пользователем (даже если впоследствии выбор был снят):

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper'),
      info  = document.querySelector('.info');
let firstChecked = null; 
const fcHandler = e => {
  if ((e.target.type !== 'checkbox') || !e.target.checked) 
    return; 
  wrapper.removeEventListener('change', fcHandler); 
  info.textContent = 'first checked: ' + (firstChecked = e.target).id; 
}; 
wrapper.addEventListener('change', fcHandler);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="group">
        <h4>Item Group 1</h4>
        <div>
            <label for="item-1">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-1" value="1">item1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="item-2">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-2" value="2" checked>item2
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h4>Item Group 2</h4>
        <div>
            <label for="item-3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-3" value="3">item3
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="item-4">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-4" value="4">item4
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">first checked: </div>
</div>
```

---

Есть еще вариант, с использованием параметра слушателя `once`... Но в данном случае, это менее гибко, ведь обработчик выполнится *однократно* (даже если пользователь *снял выбор* с чекбокса в изначально в отмеченном состоянии) - то есть, применимо только если все чекбоксы неотмечены на момент добавления слушателя:

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper'),
      info  = document.querySelector('.info');
let firstChecked = null; 
wrapper.addEventListener('change', e => {
  if ((e.target.type === 'checkbox') && e.target.checked) 
    info.textContent = 'first checked: ' + (firstChecked = e.target).id; 
}, { once: true });
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="group">
        <h4>Item Group 1</h4>
        <div>
            <label for="item-1">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-1" value="1">item1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="item-2">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-2" value="2" checked>item2
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <h4>Item Group 2</h4>
        <div>
            <label for="item-3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-3" value="3">item3
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="item-4">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-4" value="4">item4
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">first checked: </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Пожалуйста ;) Если хочется сделать все максимально чисто - объявление обработчика и его добавление можно обернуть в IIFE: тогда, по идее, сборщик мусора приберет ставшие ненужными объекты (после того как слушатель будет удален, а удаляется он после выполнения его задачи).